# How to eliminate dialog box:Header Record Delimiters

Tags: vba, ms-word

I would like to do automatic Mailings in Word, where I can change f.ex. `<<value1>>` on "Ania". So when I try to connect to my database, it shows me an eliminate dialog box : Header Record Delimiters. Our project requries this to be fully automated, so I don't want this dialog box. How do I eliminate it automatically?

This is my database:

```
"value1","value2";
"Anna2","Marek1";
```

This is my VB:

```
Sub TestMacro()

ActiveDocument.MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:= _
   "D:\Users\anna\Desktop\test2.txt", ConfirmConversions:=False, _
    ReadOnly:=False, LinkToSource:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
    PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", WritePasswordDocument:="", _
    WritePasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
    Connection:="", SQLStatement:="", SQLStatement1:="", SubType:= _
    wdMergeSubTypeOther
ActiveDocument.Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldMergeField _
    , Text:="""value1"""
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: I would like to do it automatic this settings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can avoid the issue entirely by editing the data source to a format Word will automatically recognise. Try:

```
Sub Demo()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Const StrSrc As String = "D:\Users\anna\Desktop\test2.txt"
Documents.Open StrSrc, False, False, False
With ActiveDocument
  With .Range.Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = False
    .MatchWildcards = False
    .Text = ""","""
    .Replacement.Text = Chr(34) & vbTab & Chr(34)
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
    .Text = ";^p"
    .Replacement.Text = "^p"
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
  .Close True
End With
With ActiveDocument
  .MailMerge.OpenDataSource Name:=StrSrc, ConfirmConversions:=False, _
    ReadOnly:=False, LinkToSource:=True, AddToRecentFiles:=False, _
    PasswordDocument:="", PasswordTemplate:="", WritePasswordDocument:="", _
    WritePasswordTemplate:="", Revert:=False, Format:=wdOpenFormatAuto, _
    Connection:="", SQLStatement:="", SQLStatement1:="", SubType:= _
    wdMergeSubTypeOther
  .Fields.Add Range:=Selection.Range, Type:=wdFieldMergeField, Text:="""value1"""
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

As I recall it should work by duplicating the first row, with the field names:

```
"value1","value2"
"value1","value2"
"Anna2","Marek1"
```

Note that for Word you should also use a new line as the record separator, not a semi-colon or anything else.